# How do I get to this element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select this element with Python Selenium, but don't know how since it does not contain and id/class name/etc..

Here is the HTML:

```
<img src="/resource/1599091587000/nforce__SLDS0102/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png">
```

I've tried:

```
chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(text(),'/resource/1599091587000/nforce__SLDS0102/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png')]")
```

Comment: target src attribute... something like: chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'chevrondown_60')]")

Comment: either share the url or try yourself to open the webdeveloper tool (in firefox press F12) and then copy either the css selector or the xpath, that should work

Comment: You can try to locate the element using surrounding elements (for example its parent). What is the surrounding HTML? It may actually be more reliable work than relying on src content.

Answer (score 0):

Since `text()` searches for the inner text for the HTML tag, you should not use that to search for this particular element since the URL is in the `src` attribute.

You may search it using the `src` attribute

`//img[@src='/resource/1599091587000/nforce__SLDS0102/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png')]`

or just a part of it using

`//img[contains(@src,'chevrondown_60')]`

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be a dynamic element. So to locate the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = chrome_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src^='/resource'][src$='assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[starts-with(@src, '/resource') and contains(@src, 'assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png')]")
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src^='/resource'][src$='assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(chrome_browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[starts-with(@src, '/resource') and contains(@src, 'assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```